# How can I connect to NFS from finder?

Tags: finder, macos, nfs

When I'm reading this guide it seems to be quite straightforward.

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH18705?viewlocale=en_US

But I was expecting to be typing the ip address. I don't understand what they mean by

```
nfs://DNSname/pathname
```

DNSname and pathname. Can someone elaborate?

(I'm trying to connect to my seagate business storage nas)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to mount an NFS share as a client, you need essentially two things:

1. The name or IP address of the server, referred to as DNSName
2. The share path

**How do you find this stuff out?**

This assumes you **don't** know what the share paths are.  If you already know, skip down to "Connecting"

Using my own personal Synology Diskstation as an example, I have shared two directories via NFS.  It's DNS name is diskstation.home.  Its IP address is 192.168.1.50 (not really, but it is for the sake of this example)

Launch the Terminal App.

At the prompt, type the following command:

```
showmount -e diskstation.home
(replace diskstation.home with your DNSname or IP Address)
```

In my example, the following is displayed:

```
$ showmount -e diskstation.home
Exports list on diskstation.home:
/volume1/netbackup                  *
/volume1/Network Share              *
```

Ok...so now I know what the two "share paths" are.  It's time to connect.

**Connecting**

Let's use finder:

Press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> to bring up the "Connect to Server" Dialog Box.
In the "Server Address" box, type enter the values in the format:

```
nfs://DNSName/path
or
nfs://IP/path
```

So, going back to my example, I would type:

```
nfs://diskstation.home/volume1/netbackup
or
nfs://192.168.1.50/volume1/netbackup
```

You should now be able to browse your network share.

Comment: "The folder can't be found" .. yet the same path (minus the nfs:// part) works when passed to the mount command under Linux

Answer (score 3):

After choosing 'Connect to Server...' in Finder with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> you may also use an IP-address instead of the DNS-name.

So if your NAS is at 192.168.1.10 (or mynas.example.home) and you've exported a share called 'Share', make sure the NAS provides you the entire pathname - sometimes they'll append /mnt/ (or /mount/ or /nfs/) to the path.

Instead of simple nfs://192.168.1.10/Share (or nfs://mynas.example.home/Share) you'd use nfs://192.168.1.10/mnt/Share (or nfs://mynas.example.home/mnt/Share) then.

Answer (score 2):

They are telling you to use the "DNSname/pathname" because using DNS is preferred to using IP addresses in most cases (humans typically remember words better than numbers).

However, this is contingent upon you having DNS configured.

Using the device's IP address and path to the share will work just fine, it just isn't as friendly for remembering the address and telling other people how to access it.